# Vb script error connecting Oracle

Tags: oracle, vbscript

I am trying to connect to oracle database through vbscipt(.vbs file). But, am facing the following error which am not able to solve for a very long time even though i tried with all possible combination of providers. Here is my code:

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strConnect = "Provider=MSDAORA.1; CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SIH_PROD)) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SIH_PROD))
(HOST=&host id &)(PORT= &port no&))) ;User ID=Vinod;Password=Vinodhp123" 
cn.open strConnect
```

I got the connection string value using tnsping . Am getting the error "Provider not found" and sometimes "Provider not loadable".

Kindly help me in finding the issue.

Regards,
Vinod

Answer (score 0):

According to [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/) the connection string should look like this:

```
SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));
uid=myUsername;pwd=myPassword;
```

If hostname and port number are VBScript variables, you need to concatenate them to the rest of the connection string like this:

```
strConnect = "SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
             "(HOST=" & host & ")(PORT=" & port & "))" & _
             "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));" & _
             "uid=myUsername;pwd=myPassword;"
```

because VBScript doesn't expand variables inside strings.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. Now i tried your way. Still it's showing the same error.                                         Here is my code:                                           strConnect = "Provider=MSDAORA.1;SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _
             "(HOST=44.139.1.134 )(PORT=1237))" & _
             "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SIH_PROD)));" & _
             "uid=vinod;pwd=vinodhp123;"

Comment: There is no `Provider=MSDAORA.1;` in the example.

Comment: if i use the code without provider it's showing Data cource not found : No deafult driver

Comment: That sounds like the provider/driver isn't installed (correctly). Could also be an architecture issue if you have a 64-bit system (e.g. 64-bit driver and 32-bit script interpreter or vice versa).

Comment: Hi..Any idea to find te right provider??...still..when i use this provider in vba, it's connecting but problem is coming only in vb script

Comment: No, sorry. I have only very, very limited experience with Oracle.